# make __str__ or __repr__ return list as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I'm using python 3.3.4. Here is my code:

```
class ojaxi(object):
    nomeri = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.wevri = []

    def damateba(self, adamiani):
        if adamiani in self.wevri:
            print("We Already Have That one")
        else:
            self.wevri.append(adamiani)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.wevri



class adamiani(ojaxi):
    def __init__(self, saxeli, shuasax, asaki):
        self.saxeli = saxeli
        self.shuasax = shuasax
        self.asaki = asaki

    def __str__(self):
        return self




baramidze = ojaxi()
N1 = adamiani("tyler", "durden", 18)
N2 = adamiani("joe", "black", 20)
baramidze.damateba(N1)
baramidze.damateba(N2)


print(baramidze)
```

Problem i have is that i can't make a function print out all the members in "baramidze". I want `__repr__` or `__str__` to print out something like this:
`["N1", "N2"]`

all i get is an error saying:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you must return a string from `__str__`. To do what you want you may like this :

```
def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.wevri)
```

Comment: i got this:
[<__main__.adamiani object at 0x02DFA070>, <__main__.adamiani object at 0x02DFA4D0>]

but the thing i want to print out N1 and N2

Comment: @user3503143 Call repr() on the array, not the adamiani object.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join(self.saxeli+self.shuasax+str(self.asaki))
```

Comment: In that case i got this error:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, adamiani found

Comment: in your edited version i get:
AttributeError: 'ojaxi' object has no attribute 'saxe

Comment: @user3503143, Did you copy my code correctly because there is no `saxe` in my code, only `saxeli`. Would kindly copy the code again? Thank you

Comment: i copied error inccorectly i'm sorry. same error:
AttributeError: 'ojaxi' object has no attribute 'saxeli'